# Security when getting data from MySQL/PHP via JSON in XCode

Tags: mysql, xcode, json, security

I’m making a company pricelist app for the iPhone.

Most of my application is finished, except for the “security” part.

I use PHP to extract from the SQL database, and encode it as JSON.
All this is fine, except….

I would like to protect my pricelist data from others not accessing the URL request from a browser.
I’m not a great web / php programmer and I’m not sure how to implement this on the serverside.

For now I have just made a user/password in the URLRequest like

www.hopepage.com/searchDB?User=Jack&Pass=Jones&Comp=iPhone%

In the PHP I have then made something like

IF user and pass in user database then
    Select * from components where comp like &Comp

However, this request shows my login in the URL string, an what is somebody sniffs this string ? I guess this is fairly easily possible ?

I have read a bit about SSL and HTTPS, but I’m not sure how to implement it on the serverside.

Anybody knows about good documentation, or can lead me in the right direction ?
Maybe a tutorial hidden somewhere on the net (I have searched, but maybe not used the correct words).
Anybody

Comment: if the problem is exposing those in url, then why don't you try for making post requests, though passing plain text password is bad thing.

Comment: I guess it's my missing knowledge about development for the web... would you briefly describe the "post request" method

Comment: Aaaaarh - found some documentation :)
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp

Comment: You are welcome, i've just seen your comments. Sounds good.